# DIfference between 206 Sales Invoice and 1306 Mini Sales Invoice Dynamics NAV

Tags: report, rdlc, microsoft-dynamics

I would have like to know what are the major difference between those 2 different objects. Basically i know that the Mini Sales report was placed to be adapted to Word Layout. But is there any type of drawback or major difference between the "old" and "new (mini)" objects

```
204 Sales - Quote
205 Order Confirmation
206 Sales - Invoice No  
207 Sales - Credit Memo 
208 Sales - Shipment
```

VS

```
1304    Mini Sales - Quote
1305    Mini Sales - Order Conf.
1306    Mini Sales - Invoice
1307    Mini Sales - Credit Memo
1316    Mini Statement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some years in reporting now. The reports are almost the same and the mini sales is different in layout. That is the rdlc design is competely different and I have learnt a lot from it. The mini does not contain any header or footer but everything is in the body which is best since you dont require the setdata and getdata on the 206 reports.

I would recommend having a lot at those mini reports ;) they can help learn something in reports!